# Big sprites vs small sprites in a COCOS2D-X scene

Tags: game-engine, cocos2d-x

I'm working on a 2D physic game based on a complex graphic scenario. For my first level I've created all graphics with several instances of base (relatively small) images (sprites). This approach results in performance issues because of large number of sprites to draw (about 350) on old phones like iPhone4.

In second stage, I've used a different approach: I created a big image for the entire level, I've split that in 10 slices and put these sprites on the scene. This approach give High performance improvement, and give me the freedom to create a very rich level in terms of graphics, but take very large amount of space (about 40 mb for a single level).

In your opinion, where is the solution? In the middle? 
For example "Rayman Jungle run" take about 100 mb for all (many) levels...

This is a resource organization problem, not a technical question, but is very interesting to know different approaches.

Here a screenshot of the scenario.[scenario http://www.youmble.com/site/sites/default/files/scenario.png](http://www.youmble.com/site/sites/default/files/scenario.png)

Thanks in advance.
Marco

Comment: Did you batch draw the sprites? Please provide the size of the entire scene and the sizes of individual chunks and file format (png? jpg? pvr?). Also, whether you have 350 sprites or 10 sprites covering the exact same area, the memory usage of either one should not differ by much. Don't look at the file sizes, image files are compressed, textures are not (unless you use PVR textures). Check this for more info: http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/2012/11/optimize-memory-usage-bundle-size-cocos2d-app/

Comment: Yes. I created them with TP. I used PNGs because of some problems of pvr.ccz on Android. The entire scene is 20000x1536 (at its full size), each chunk is 2000x1536, so we have 10 chunks. My big problem is not the memory usage, but the bundle size. With many small sprites (reused many times in the scene) the bundle is small, because we reuse same sprites many times, by rotating and scaling it. With big chunks, no reuse is possible in term of graphic, but the bundle is too big. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: Another detail: as shown in the screenshot, we have 2 layer, one for the game another for the parallax; so we have different chunks for every layer (10 for the main layer, 5 for the parallax layer).

Comment: Have you tried using the smaller chunks but not loading them all, instead showing only those on the screen and one screen ahead. You can asynch load textures in a background thread. Also do you use CCSpriteBatchNode to draw all the sprites of the same texture?

Comment: Yes. I've used CCSpriteBatchNode for all sprites. In effect I don't have performance problems, I only need need a different strategy for implement levels... Thanks for all